# Admin Dashboard layout with Bourbon Neat

Tags: fixed, sidebar, dashboard, bourbon, neat

Is there a way to make a sidebar with a position fixed 
and make the content align to a grid like Bourbon Neat?

A good example of what i'm trying to do is like the bourbon neat doc page: http://thoughtbot.github.io/neat-docs/latest/

I don't want the sidebar to resize I want it fixed, I want the first columns of the grid to start directly after the sidebar. Maybe there is a simpler solutions but this is the only one that comes in my mind.

I know without a grid I can make a content-wrap div with a left margin that span the size of my sidebar. But I kinda want to work with a grid to align my widget that I will create in the content area.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a way to do it if someone want to know i use the calc mixins from bourbon on a content-wrap div like this:

```
.page-wrap{
  @include calc(width, '100% - $sidebar-width');
  margin-left: $sidebar-width;
};
```

I've made another div inside this one and gave it the outer-container mixins. Now i can align others div inside it by using the span-columns mixins on them.

Comment: Out of interest, why is calc needed if it's 100% anyway?